# Sensibility of converting Matlab program in Java to improve performance

Tags: java, matlab, genetic-algorithm, sudoku

His

I have a somewhat hypothetical question. We've just programmed some code implementing genetic algorithm to find a solution to a sudoku game as part of the Computational Intelligence course project. Unfortunately it runs very slowly which limits our ability to perform adequate number of runs to find the optimal parameters. The question is whether reprogramming the whole thing - the code basis is not that big - into java would be a viable solution to boost up the speed of the software. Like we need 10x performance improvement really and i am doubtful that a Java version would be so much snappier. Any thoughts?

Thanks

=== Update 1 ===

Here is the code of the function that is computationally most expensive. It's a GA fitness function, that iterates through the population (different sudoku boards) and computes for each row and column how many elements are duplicates. The parameter n is passed, and is currently set to 9. That is, the function computes how many elements a row has that come up within the range 1 to 9 more then once. The higher the number the less is the fitness of the board, meaning that it is a weak candidate for the next generation.

The profiler reports that the two lines calling intersect in the for loops causing the poor performance, but we don't know how to really optimize the code. It follows below:

```
function [fitness, finished,d, threshold]=fitness(population_, n)
finished=false;
threshold=false;
V=ones(n,1);
d=zeros(size(population_,2),1);
s=[1:1:n];
for z=1:size(population_,2)
    board=population_{z};
    t=0;
    l=0;
    for i=1:n
        l=l+n-length(intersect(s,board(:,i)'));
        t=t+n-length(intersect(s,board(i,:)));

    end
    k=sum(abs(board*V-t));

    f=t+l+k/50;
    if t==2 &&l==2
        threshold=true;
    end
    if f==0
        finished=true;        
    else
        fitness(z)=1/f;
        d(z)=f;
    end
end
end
```

=== Update 2 ===

Found a solution here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112771-how-to-optimize-the-following-function

Using histc(V, 1:9), it's much faster :)

Comment: Why not throw more hardware at it? In any case, Java may very well run  much faster, as it is a compiled language (as opposed to MATLAB, which if I'm reading correctly, is interpreted)

Comment: I don't know how much is Java integrated with Matlab with respect to other languages; if you already are going to rewrite it, it may be even better to use a fully compiled language like C++ (provided that you know both, of course)

Comment: And, if Matlab provides methods to take advantage of parallel processing (I don't know that, but I'd say that it should), did you gave a look at that option?

Comment: yes, we did. but only one small section can be parallelized (with a parfor loop). 

what  we need is a major improvement in performance. A two-times improvement will not suffice, so that is why i am so doubtful

Comment: In my experience, you would find a bigger performance improvement by improving your algorithm, rather than porting your code. Running identical algorithms, MATLAB generally isn't that much slower than C, and certainly not 10x slower.

Comment: MrAzzaman, that's what i thought too. It may be slower, but certainly not that much...

Comment: One thing you can do is use the MATLAB profiler (**Desktop** > **Profiler**) to see where in your code most of your execution time is going. You may find you have one or two bottlenecks in your code which are greatly slowing down your program.

Comment: yes, we've already done that. And it turns out to be either setdiff or unique function calls. the problem is, that they are called from the other built-in matlab functions and thus cannot be optimized

Comment: Is the inner computation function small enough to post?

Comment: @Peter, which inner computation function do you mean?

Comment: Not your whole code, but the portion that takes all the time.  I'm suggesting that this community may be able to offer MATLAB optimization advice, or be able to offer better estimates on potential speedups by going to C++ or Java.  It could be anywhere between 1x and 100x, depending on your current code.

Comment: Peter, I have edited the post and inserted there a function that takes most of the time.

Comment: 's' in the intersect call is undefined

Comment: corrected the code now

Comment: So, how'd it go?  Does 300x solve your problem?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112771-how-to-optimize-the-following-function

Using histc(V, 1:9) - it's so much faster :)

Comment: You can use whatever you like, I just thought I'd mention that my answer below is not only twice as fast as the histc solution, but also gives the exact same results as your original code.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather impossible to say without viewing your code, knowing if you use parallelization, etc. Indeed, as MrAzzaman says, profiling is the first thing to do. If you find a single bottleneck, especially if it is loop-heavy, it might be sufficient to write that part in C and connect it to Matlab via MEX.

In genetics algorithms, I'd believe that a 10x speed increase could be obtained rather than not. I do not quite agree with MrAzzaman here - in some cases (for loops, working with dynamic objects) is much, much slower than C/C++/Java. That is not to say that Matlab is always slow, for it is not, but there is plenty of algorithms where it would be slow.

I.e., I'd say that if you don't spend so much time looping over things, don't use objects, are not limited by Matlab's data structures, you might be ok with Matlab. That said, if I was to write GAs in Java or Matlab, I'd rather pick the former (and I'm using Matlab a lot more than Java these days, it's not just a matter of habit).

Btw. if you don't want to program it yourself, have a look at JGAP, it's a rather useful Java library for GAs.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments. I've just posted an update with a function that shows the worst performance in the code. Maybe you could take a look and suggest how to optimize the for loop code, it basically kills the performance...

Answer (score 1):

OK, the first step is just to write a faster MATLAB function.  Save the new languages for later.

I'm going to make the assumption that the board is full of valid guesses: that is, each entry is in [1, 9].  Now, what we're really looking for are duplicate entries in each row/column.  To find duplicates, we sort.  On a sorted row, if any element is equal to its neighbor, we have a duplicate.  In MATLAB, the `diff` function does sliding pairwise differencing, and a zero in its output means that two neighboring values are equal.  Both sort and diff operate on entire matrices, so no need for looping.  Here's the code for the columnwise check:

```
l=sum(sum(diff(sort(board)) == 0));
```

The rowwise check is exactly the same, just using the transpose.  Now let's put that in a test harness to compare results and timing with the previous version:

```
n = 9;
% Generate a test board.  Random integers numbers from 1:n
board = randi(n, n);

s = 1:n;
K=1000; % number of iterations to use for timing

% Repeat current code for comparison
tic
for k=1:K
    t=0;
    l=0;
    for i=1:n
        l=l+n-length(intersect(s,board(:,i)'));
        t=t+n-length(intersect(s,board(i,:)));
    end
end
toc

% New code based on sort/diff for finding repeated values
tic
for k=1:K
    l2=sum(sum(diff(sort(board)) == 0));
    t2=sum(sum(diff(sort(board.')) == 0));
end
toc

% Check that reported values match
disp([l l2])
disp([t t2])
```

I encourage you to break down the sort/diff/sum code, and build it up on a sample `board` right at the command line, and try to understand exactly how it works.

On my system, the new code is about 330x faster.

Answer (score 0):

For traditional GA applications for studying and research purposes it is better to use a native machine compiled source code programming language, like C, C++. Which I used when working with Genetic 
Programming in the past and it is really fast.

However if you are planning to put this inside a more modern type of application that can be deployed in a web container or run in a mobile device, different OS, etc. Then Java is your best alternative as it is platform independent.

Another thing that can be important is about concurrency. For example lets us suppose that you want to put your GA in the Internet and you will have a growing number of users that are connected concurrently and all of them want to solve a different sudoku, Java applications are very good for scaling horizontally and works great with big number of concurrent connections.

Other thing that can be good if you migrate to Java is the number of libraries and frameworks that you can use, the Java universe is so big that you can find useful tools for almost any kind of application.

Java is a Virtual Machine compiled language, but it is important to note that currently the JVMs are very good in performance and are able to optimize the programs, for example they will find which methods are being more heavily used and compile them to native code, which means that for some applications you will find a Java program to be almost same fast than a native compiled from C.

Matlab is a platform that is very useful for engineering training and math, vector, matrix based calculations, also for some control stuff with Simulink. I used these products when in my electrical engineering bachelor, however those product's goal is to be mainly a tool for academic purposes I won't definitely go for Matlab if I am wanting to build a production application for the real world. It is not scalable, it is expensive to maintain and fine-tune it, also there are not lot of infrastructure providers that will support this kind of technology.

About the complexity of rewriting your code to Java, the Matlab code and Java code syntax is pretty similar, they also live in the same paradigm: Procedural OOP, even if you are not using OO in your code it can be easy rewritten in Java, the painful stuff will be when working with Matlab shortcuts to Math structures like matrix and passing functions as parameters.

For the matrix stuff, there are lot of java libraries like EJML that will make your life easier. About assigning functions to variables and then pass them as parameters to another functions, Java is not currently able to do that (Java 8 will be with Lambda Expressions) but you can have a equivalent functionality by using Class closures. Maybe these will be the only little painful things that you will find if migrating.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112771-how-to-optimize-the-following-function

Using histc(V, 1:9), it's much faster :)